# ¿Se puede conectar una App de Android Xamarin, a sql server directamente o es necesario consumir alguna WebApi o alguna otra forma?

Tags: sql-server, xamarin, xamarin.android

estoy iniciando en las app móviles, y tengo una App que necesita traer todos los datos de sql server "online", intenté conectar la App a sql server como si se tratase de un WinForm, y cuando está conectado a la PC el smartphone de prueba y empiezo a debuggear, hace correctamente los select, insert, update, etc, pero cuando lo desconecto de la pc, y abro la App, quiero que haga un select, y no hace nada la App, como si ésta no se estuviera conectando a SQL, ¿hay alguna forma diferente de conectar la App a SQL Server?
Aquí tengo un ejemplo que tengo en la App sobre un login que hice, y que me funciona sólo cuando está conectado a la PC el smartphone de prueba

```
 ConexionController con = new ConexionController();
        cTripleDES decry = new cTripleDES();
        SqlConnection miConexion =new SqlConnection( "data source = snare.arvixe.com; initial catalog=logins; user id=******; password= ******");
        public int Login(string user, string password)
        {
            try
            {   
                if (miConexion.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    miConexion.Open();
                }
                SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand("select email, clave from CrmCustomers where email = '" + user + "'and clave = '" + password + "' ", miConexion);
                comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(comando);
                da.Fill(ds, "CrmCustomers");
                DataRow DR;
                DR = ds.Tables["CrmCustomers"].Rows[0];
                if ((user == DR["email"].ToString()) && (password == DR["clave"].ToString()))
                {
                    miConexion.Close();
                    return 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    miConexion.Close();
                    return 2;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                miConexion.Close();
                return 3;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Me quedo la duda si estabas ejecutando la app en el emulador o en un teléfono, si en el simulador le funciona bien podría ser un tema de configuración del azure, que tiene restringidas cuales ip permitir conexión

Comment: Es un smartphone físico,y sólo cuando estoy conectado a la PC hace bien todos los querys de SQL, cuando se desconecta no hace nada la App, por eso mi duda es, si debería hacer algún servicio web y consumirlo desde el smartphone

Comment: la app tiene permiso para internet en el manifiesto? `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Comment: Acabo de revisar que en Xamarin Android, el manisfest se maneja de parte gráfica, https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/general/projects/add_permissions_to_android_manifest/
ya di permisos a internet, y ya conecta a sql, lo que veo raro, es que conectado a la pc, nunca dio problema el permiso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yo que tu haria un webservice, es mas seguro y mejor para usarlo con volley, de todas formas, deberias poder hacerlo sin problemas, revisaste los persmios del usuario en la base de datos? desde que host esta permitido la conexion? que motor de base de datos es?
te fijaste la conexion externa del servidor? que este autorizado el acceso externo a la base?

Comment: Cierto, por la noche estuve revisando los beneficios de un webservice, y parece que la seguridad es mayor, puesto que de ésta forma, el móvil (smartphone) no se conecta de manera directa a SQL, y así evitar tener la conexión casi siempre abierta, es mejor hacer la petición al webservice, y que éste haga la conexión a SQL